# C++ Lambda Code Generation with Init Captures in C++ 14

Tags: c++, lambda, c++14, move

I am trying to understand / clarify the code code that is generated when captures are passed to lambdas especially in generalized init captures added in C++14.

Give the following code samples listed below this is my current understanding of what the compiler will generate.

Case 1: capture by value / default capture by value

```
int x = 6;
auto lambda = [x]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
```

Would equate to:

```
class __some_compiler_generated_name {
public:
    __some_compiler_generated_name(int x) : __x{x}{}
    void operator()() const { std::cout << __x << std::endl;}
private:
    int __x;
};
```

So there are multiple copies, one to copy into the constructor parameter and one to copy into the member, which would be expensive for types like vector etc.

Case 2: capture by reference / default capture by reference

```
int x = 6;
auto lambda = [&x]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
```

Would equate to:

```
class __some_compiler_generated_name {
public:
    __some_compiler_generated_name(int& x) : x_{x}{}
    void operator()() const { std::cout << x << std::endl;}
private:
    int& x_;
};
```

The parameter is a reference and the member is a reference so no copies. Nice for types like vector etc.

Case 3:

Generalised init capture

```
auto lambda = [x = 33]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
```

My under standing is this is similar to Case 1 in the sense 
that it is copied into to the member.

My guess is that the compiler generates code similar to...

```
class __some_compiler_generated_name {
public:
    __some_compiler_generated_name() : __x{33}{}
    void operator()() const { std::cout << __x << std::endl;}
private:
    int __x;
};
```

Also if I have the following:

```
auto l = [p = std::move(unique_ptr_var)]() {
 // do something with unique_ptr_var
};
```

What would the constructor look like? Does it also move it into the member?

Comment: @rafix07 In that case the generated insight code won't even compile (it tries to copy-initialize the unique ptr member from the argument). cppinsights is useful for getting a general gist, but it's clearly not able to answer this here question.

Comment: You seem to assume there's a translation of lambda's to functors as a first step of compilation, or are you merely looking for equivalent code (ie. same behavior) ? The way a specific compiler generates code (and which code it generates) will depend on compiler, version, architecture, flags, etc. So, are you asking for a specific platform ? If not, your question is not really answerable. Other than the actual generated code will probably be more efficient than the functors you list (eg. inlined constructors, avoiding unnecessary copies, etc.).

Comment: If you're interested in what the C++ standard has to say about it, refer to *[expr.prim.lambda]*. It's too much to summarize here as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question cannot be fully answered in code. You might be able to write somewhat "equivalent" code, but the standard is not specified that way.

With that out of the way, let's dive into [`[expr.prim.lambda]`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda). The first thing to note is that constructors are only mentioned in [`[expr.prim.lambda.closure]/13`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-13):

> The closure type associated with a *lambda-expression* has no default constructor if the *lambda-expression* has a *lambda-capture* and a defaulted default constructor otherwise. It has a defaulted copy constructor and a defaulted move constructor ([class.copy.ctor]). It has a deleted copy assignment operator if the *lambda-expression* has a *lambda-capture* and defaulted copy and move assignment operators otherwise ([class.copy.assign]). [ *Note:* These special member functions are implicitly defined as usual, and might therefore be defined as deleted. — *end note* ]

So right off the bat, it should be clear that constructors are not formally how capturing objects is defined. You can get pretty close (see the cppinsights.io answer), but the details differ (note how the code in that answer for case 4 does not compile).

---

These are the main standard clauses needed to discuss case 1:

[`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/10`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-10)

> [...]
>   For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type.
>   The declaration order of these members is unspecified.
>   The type of such a data member is the referenced type if the entity is a reference to an object, an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity is a reference to a function, or the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise.
>   A member of an anonymous union shall not be captured by copy.

[`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/11`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-11)

> Every *id-expression* within the compound-statement of a *lambda-expression* that is an odr-use of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type. [...]

[`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/15`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-15)

> When the lambda-expression is evaluated, the entities that are captured by copy are used to direct-initialize each corresponding non-static data member of the resulting closure object, and the non-static data members corresponding to the init-captures are initialized as indicated by the corresponding initializer (which may be copy- or direct-initialization). [...]

Let's apply this to your case 1:

> Case 1: capture by value / default capture by value
>
> ```
> int x = 6;
> auto lambda = [x]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
> ```

The closure type of this lambda will have an unnamed non-static data member (let's call it `__x`) of type `int` (since `x` is neither a reference nor a function), and accesses to `x` within the lambda body are transformed to accesses to `__x`. When we evaluate the lambda expression (i.e. when assigning to `lambda`), we [direct-initialize](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization) `__x` with `x`.

In short, **only one copy takes place**. The constructor of the closure type is not involved, and it is not possible to express this in "normal" C++ (note that the closure type [is not an aggregate type](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#closure-2.sentence-4) either).

---

Reference capture involve [`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/12`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-12):

> An entity is *captured by reference* if it is implicitly or explicitly captured but not captured by copy. It is unspecified whether additional unnamed non-static data members are declared in the closure type for entities captured by reference. [...]

There is another paragraph about reference capture of references but we're not doing that anywhere.

So, for case 2:

> Case 2: capture by reference / default capture by reference
>
> ```
> int x = 6;
> auto lambda = [&x]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
> ```

We don't know whether a member is added to the closure type. `x` in the lambda body might just directly refer to the `x` outside. This is up to the compiler to figure out, and it will do this in some form of intermediate language (which differs from compiler to compiler), not a source transformation of the C++ code.

---

Init captures are detailed in [`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-6):

> An init-capture behaves as if it declares and explicitly captures a variable of the form `auto init-capture ;` whose declarative region is the lambda-expression's compound-statement, except that:
>
> - (6.1)
>     if the capture is by copy (see below), the non-static data member declared for the capture and the variable are treated as two different ways of referring to the same object, which has the lifetime of the non-static data member, and no additional copy and destruction is performed, and
> - (6.2)
>     if the capture is by reference, the variable's lifetime ends when the closure object's lifetime ends.

Given that, let's look at case 3:

> Case 3: Generalised init capture
>
> ```
> auto lambda = [x = 33]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
> ```

As stated, imagine this as a variable being created by `auto x = 33;` and explicitly captured by copy. This variable is only "visible" within the lambda body. As noted in [`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/15`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-15) earlier, the initialization of the corresponding member of the closure type (`__x` for posterity) is by the given initializer upon evaluation of the lambda expression.

For the avoidance of doubt: This does not mean things are initialized twice here. The `auto x = 33;` is an "as if" to inherit the semantics of simple captures, and the described initialization is a modification to those semantics. Only one initialization happens.

This also covers case 4:

> ```
> auto l = [p = std::move(unique_ptr_var)]() {
>   // do something with unique_ptr_var
> };
> ```

The closure type member is initialized by `__p = std::move(unique_ptr_var)` when the lambda expression is evaluated (i.e. when `l` is assigned to). Accesses to `p` in the lambda body are transformed into accesses to `__p`.

---

**TL;DR: Only the minimal number of copies/initializations/moves are performed (as one would hope/expect).** I would assume that lambdas are *not* specified in terms of a source transformation (unlike other syntactic sugar) exactly *because* expressing things in terms of constructors would necessitate superfluous operations.

I hope this settles the fears expressed in the question :)

Answer (score 10):

There's less of a need to speculate, using [cppinsights.io](https://cppinsights.io).

**Case 1:**
Code

```cpp
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int x = 33;
    auto lambda = [x]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
}
```

Compiler generates

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x = 6;

  class __lambda_5_16
  {
    int x;
    public: 
    inline void operator()() const
    {
      std::cout.operator<<(x).operator<<(std::endl);
    }

    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_5_16(const __lambda_5_16 &) = default;
    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_5_16(__lambda_5_16 &&) noexcept = default;
    public: __lambda_5_16(int _x)
    : x{_x}
    {}

  };

  __lambda_5_16 lambda = __lambda_5_16(__lambda_5_16{x});
}
```

**Case 2:**
Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    int x = 33;
    auto lambda = [&x]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
}
```

Compiler generates

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int x = 6;

  class __lambda_5_16
  {
    int & x;
    public: 
    inline void operator()() const
    {
      std::cout.operator<<(x).operator<<(std::endl);
    }

    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_5_16(const __lambda_5_16 &) = default;
    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_5_16(__lambda_5_16 &&) noexcept = default;
    public: __lambda_5_16(int & _x)
    : x{_x}
    {}

  };

  __lambda_5_16 lambda = __lambda_5_16(__lambda_5_16{x});
}
```

**Case 3:**
Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    auto lambda = [x = 33]() { std::cout << x << std::endl; };
}
```

Compiler generates

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

  class __lambda_4_16
  {
    int x;
    public: 
    inline void operator()() const
    {
      std::cout.operator<<(x).operator<<(std::endl);
    }

    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_4_16(const __lambda_4_16 &) = default;
    // inline /*constexpr */ __lambda_4_16(__lambda_4_16 &&) noexcept = default;
    public: __lambda_4_16(int _x)
    : x{_x}
    {}

  };

  __lambda_4_16 lambda = __lambda_4_16(__lambda_4_16{33});
}
```

**Case 4 (unofficially):**
Code

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main() {
    auto x = std::make_unique<int>(33);
    auto lambda = [x = std::move(x)]() { std::cout << *x << std::endl; };
}
```

Compiler generates

```cpp
// EDITED output to minimize horizontal scrolling
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

int main()
{
  std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > x = 
      std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> >(std::make_unique<int>(33));

  class __lambda_6_16
  {
    std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > x;
    public: 
    inline void operator()() const
    {
      std::cout.operator<<(x.operator*()).operator<<(std::endl);
    }

    // inline __lambda_6_16(const __lambda_6_16 &) = delete;
    // inline __lambda_6_16(__lambda_6_16 &&) noexcept = default;
    public: __lambda_6_16(std::unique_ptr<int, std::default_delete<int> > _x)
    : x{_x}
    {}

  };

  __lambda_6_16 lambda = __lambda_6_16(__lambda_6_16{std::unique_ptr<int, 
                                                     std::default_delete<int> >
                                                         (std::move(x))});
}
```

And I believe this last piece of code answers your question. A move occurs, but not [technically] in the constructor.

Captures themselves aren't `const`, but you can see that the `operator()` function is. Naturally, if you need to modify the captures, you mark the lambda as `mutable`.

Comment: The code you show for the last case doesn't even compile. The conclusion "a move occurs, but not [technically] in the constructor" can't be supported by that code.

Comment: The **Code** of case 4 most certainly does compile on my Mac. I am surprised that the *generated expanded code from cppinsights* doesn't compile. The site has, to this point, been quite reliable for me. I'll raise an issue with them. EDIT: I did confirm that the generated code doesn't compile; that wasn't clear without this edit.

Comment: Link to the issue in case of interest: https://github.com/andreasfertig/cppinsights/issues/258

I still recommend the site for things like testing SFINAE and whether or not implicit casts will occur.

Answer (score 9):

**Case 1** `[x](){}`: The generated constructor will accept its argument by possibly `const`-qualified reference to avoid unnecessary copies:

```
__some_compiler_generated_name(const int& x) : x_{x}{}
```

---

**Case 2** `[x&](){}`: Your assumptions here are correct, `x` is passed and stored by reference.

---

**Case 3** `[x = 33](){}`: Again correct, `x` is initialized by value.

---

**Case 4** `[p = std::move(unique_ptr_var)]`: The constructor will look like this:

```
    __some_compiler_generated_name(std::unique_ptr<SomeType>&& x) :
        x_{std::move(x)}{}
```

so yes, the `unique_ptr_var` is "moved into" the closure. See also Scott Meyer's Item 32 in Effective Modern C++ ("Use init capture to move objects into closures").

Comment: "`const`-qualified" Why?

Comment: @cpplearner Mh, good question. I guess I inserted that because one of those mental automatisms kicked in^^ At least `const` can't hurt here due to some ambiguity/better match when non-`const` etc. Anyway, do you think I should remove the `const`?

Comment: I think const should remain, what, if the argument passed to actually is const?

Comment: So you are saying that two move (or copy) constructions happen here?

Comment: Sorry, I mean in case 4 (for the moves) and case 1 (for the copies). The copy part of my question makes no sense based on your statements (but I question those statements).

Comment: @MaxLanghof I'd say two moves yes (if the `unique_ptr` argument isn't an rvalue already), two copies no (why should there be two instead of one in case1?)

Comment: The standard does not support performing two moves. The unnamed member (to which all accesses of `x` within the lambda body are transformed) is initialized directly as if by `= std::move(unique_ptr_var)`, no non-default constructor is formally invoked.

Comment: @MaxLanghof ... which means we can't express this in regular code anyway when looking for an equivalent function object?

Comment: @lubgr Yes. Normally I would brush over these differences when discussing lambdas, but the question author appears to be specifically concerned about the performance implications (such as the number of copies), and that can't really be discussed based on "the generated C++ code" because such thing does not exist.

Comment: @MaxLanghof You're right, and pedantic mode is fine especially given the OP's reasoning for the bounty. I won't try to incorporate that in my answer though, as it's covered in yours - which BTW is worth the bounty if you ask me.